# How to get height and width header?

Tags: qt, header, height, width, qtablewidget

how to get height and width header(horizontal / vertical)  from the QTableWidget on Qt.

I know get the itens from QTableWidget, but I can not capture the header.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use following methods

```
QTableWidget* tableWidget = new QTableWidget();

//
// populate widtet
//

tableWidget->horizontalHeader()->width(); //get total width of horizontal header
tableWidget->horizontalHeader()->height(); //get height of horizontal header
tableWidget->horizontalHeader()->sectionSize(0); //get width of first section
```